# How can I generate a client proxy for a WCF service with an HTTPS endpoint?

Tags: wcf, security, authentication, https

Might be the same issue as this previuos question: [WCF Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703698/generating-wcf-proxy-against-untrusted-ssl-endpoint) but not sure...

I have an HTTPS service connfigured to use transport security and, I hope, Windows credentials.  The service is only accessed internally (i.e. within the intranet).  The configuration is as follows:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFTest.CalculatorService" behaviorConfiguration="WCFTest.CalculatorBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "https://localhost:8000/WCFTest/CalculatorService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address ="basicHttpEP" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFTest.ICalculatorService" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfig"/>    
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfig">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType = "Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFTest.CalculatorBehavior">          
          <serviceAuthorization impersonateCallerForAllOperations="false"  principalPermissionMode="UseWindowsGroups" />
          <serviceCredentials >
            <windowsAuthentication allowAnonymousLogons="false" includeWindowsGroups="true" />
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

When I run the service I can't see the service in IE.  I get a "this page can not be displayed" error.  If I try and create a client in VS2008 via the "add service reference" wizard I get this error:

> There was an error downloading
>   'https://localhost:8000/WCFTest/CalculatorService/'.
>   There was an error downloading
>   'https://localhost:8000/WCFTest/CalculatorService/'.
>   The underlying connection was closed:
>   An unexpected error occurred on a
>   send. Authentication failed because
>   the remote party has closed the
>   transport stream. Metadata contains a
>   reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'https://localhost:8000/WCFTest/CalculatorService/'.
>   An error occurred while making the
>   HTTP request to
>   https://localhost:8000/WCFTest/CalculatorService/.
>   This could be due to the fact that the
>   server certificate is not configured
>   properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS
>   case. This could also be caused by a
>   mismatch of the security binding
>   between the client and the server. The
>   underlying connection was closed: An
>   unexpected error occurred on a send.
>   Authentication failed because the
>   remote party has closed the transport
>   stream. If the service is defined in
>   the current solution, try building the
>   solution and adding the service
>   reference again.

I think I'm missing some fundamental basics here.  Do I need to set up some certificates?  Or should it all just work as it seems to do when I use NetTcpBinding?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the client config?

Comment: I don't know how to limit which windows groups I'm accepting.  Is there a difference between windows groups and Active Directory groups?

Comment: I don't have a client yet.  I though I could just go though "Add Service Reference" and that would create the config for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change

```
<endpoint address ="basicHttpEP" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFTest.ICalculatorService" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfig"/>
```

to

```
<endpoint address ="basicHttpEP" binding="basicHttpsBinding" contract="WCFTest.ICalculatorService" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfig"/>
```

Comment: As far as I can see [basicHttpsBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpsbinding(v=vs.110).aspx) is available for .NET 4.5 only.

Answer (score 0):

ng5000,

Seems like you may have another issue here (maybe IIS).  Do you have any issues with transport-level security off?    I would also make sure you can get to the web address in IE before checking the WCF stuff.  Sounds like a IIS setting that's not correct in the security tab.

If its still a problem try building the proxy with transport-level security off and then go back and change both configs to transport level windows security and see what happens.

-Bryan

Comment: I'm not using IIS, I'm self hosting with a little console app.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
<security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default" authenticationMode="IssuedTokenOverTransport"
                    requireDerivedKeys="false" securityHeaderLayout="Strict" includeTimestamp="true"
                    keyEntropyMode="CombinedEntropy" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
                    <issuedTokenParameters keyType="SymmetricKey" tokenType="" />
...
```

here is my workaround. I got above config file and changed authenticationMode from "IssuedTokenOverTransport" to "UserNameOverTransport". It resolved issue on my environment.